# Transposition table causes chess engine to lose

Tags: c++, chess

Prelude: I understand this question may be a little too broad for the likes of Stack Overflow. Although, I tried to add as much information as I could come up with.

I'm coding a chess engine in C++ from scratch, and it's mostly done (except that it has a weak evaluation function). What is weird though is that the engine loses every single time the transposition table is enabled, by an amazingly obvious blunder (gives away a queen, or sometimes a queen and another piece). When the transposition table probing is disabled, the engine wins easily against both Nero and TSCP.

I use a very simple transposition table implementation with an always-replace scheme, taken from Bruce Morland's site [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20080315233307/http://www.seanet.com/~brucemo/topics/hashing.htm).

Here's the probe implementation:

```
bool probe_table(TranspositionTable& t_table, unsigned int ply,
uint64 hash_key, unsigned int depth, unsigned int& pv_move, int& score,
int alpha, int beta)
{
    unsigned int index = hash_key % t_table.num_entries;

    assert(index < t_table.num_entries);

    if(t_table.t_entry[index].hash_key == hash_key)
    {
        pv_move = t_table.t_entry[index].move;

        if(t_table.t_entry[index].depth >= depth)
        {
            score = t_table.t_entry[index].score;

            if(score > IS_MATE) score -= ply;
            else if(score < -IS_MATE) score += ply;

            switch(t_table.t_entry[index].flag)
            {
                case TFALPHA:
                {
                    if(score <= alpha)
                    {
                        score = alpha;
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
                case TFBETA:
                {
                    if(score >= beta)
                    {
                        score = beta;
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
                case TFEXACT:
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                default: assert(false); // At least one flag must be set.
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

During alpha-beta search, the table is probed (the entries are stored correctly as well, depending on cutoffs and such):

```
if(probe_table(board.t_table, board.ply, board.hash_key, depth, pv_move,
    score, alpha, beta))
{
    return score;
}
```

**Edit**: For completeness, here's a snippet of the important bits of storing code in search:

```
if(score > alpha) // Alpha cutoff.
{
    if(score >= beta) // Beta cutoff.
    {
        ...

        store_entry(board.t_table, board.ply, board.hash_key, best_move,
                    beta, depth, TFBETA);

        return beta;
    }

    alpha = score;

    ...
    }
}

...

assert(alpha >= old_alpha);

if(alpha != old_alpha)
{
    store_entry(board.t_table, board.ply, board.hash_key, best_move,
        best_score, depth, TFEXACT);
}
else
{
    store_entry(board.t_table, board.ply, board.hash_key, best_move,
        alpha, depth, TFALPHA);
}
```

I have considered and explored failures in every other part of the engine, and none is happening. Disabling the probing entirely (but still using the table to store PV lines), works beautifully.

I also considered whether my naive implementation of pondering was affecting things. To ponder, I simply print out `bestmove xxxx ponder xxxx` to UCI whenever a ponder move is available. If pondering is enabled, the GUI lets the engine ponder (which is just a regular search, but will be later used by means of the transposition table).

To test, I disabled pondering entirely, which did not show any improvement. After having a winning score for a while, the engine simply gave away its queen. I believe this is happening either due to some bad entry in the table, or perhaps some other sort of instability that I'm unable to comprehend.

And this is where I need somebody who has run into this before to point me into a general direction.

**Edit**: As grek40 asked, here's an example that just took place (the engine is white, white to move):

[image: Position]

The engine one again, lost the game based on stupid moves. Please note that the engine reached a bad position such as this one probably because of the transposition table itself.

Analysing this position ***with*** the transposition table filled during the game:

```
info score cp -425 depth 1 nodes 1 time 0 pv e1d1
info score cp -425 depth 2 nodes 2 time 0 pv e1d1
info score cp -425 depth 3 nodes 3 time 0 pv e1d1
info score cp -425 depth 4 nodes 4 time 0 pv e1d1
info score cp -425 depth 5 nodes 5 time 0 pv e1d1
info score cp -425 depth 6 nodes 6 time 0 pv e1d1
info score cp -425 depth 7 nodes 7 time 0 pv e1d1
info score cp -425 depth 8 nodes 8 time 0 pv e1d1
info score cp -425 depth 9 nodes 9 time 0 pv e1d1
info score cp -425 depth 10 nodes 10 time 0 pv e1d1
info score cp -440 depth 11 nodes 10285162 time 3673 pv f5f8 e7f8 b2b3 b7b5 e1c1 d6d5 a3a4
info score cp -440 depth 12 nodes 29407669 time 10845 pv f5f8 e7f8 e1f1 f8e7 f1f5 d6d5
bestmove f5f8 ponder e7f8
```

Analysing once again ***without*** the transposition table (actually, with the table, but cleared):

```
info score cp -415 depth 1 nodes 82 time 0 pv f5f8
info score cp -415 depth 2 nodes 200 time 0 pv f5f8 e7f8
info score cp -405 depth 3 nodes 900 time 0 pv f5f8 e7f8 b2b3
info score cp -425 depth 4 nodes 2936 time 1 pv f5f8 e7f8 b2b3 f8e7
info score cp -415 depth 5 nodes 10988 time 4 pv f5f8 e7f8 b2b3 b7b5 e1d1
info score cp -425 depth 6 nodes 65686 time 25 pv f5f8 e7f8 e1f1 d7e7 f1d1 b7b5
info score cp -420 depth 7 nodes 194124 time 76 pv f5f8 e7f8 b2b3 b7b5 e1f1 f8e7 f1f7
info score cp -425 depth 8 nodes 357753 time 141 pv f5f8 e7f8 b2b3 b7b5 e1f1 f8e7 f1f5 d7c7
info score cp -425 depth 9 nodes 779686 time 292 pv f5f8 e7f8 e1f1 f8e7 f1f5 h4h8
info score cp -425 depth 10 nodes 1484178 time 560 pv f5f8 e7f8 e1f1 f8e7 f1f5 h4h8
info score cp -435 depth 11 nodes 29481132 time 11117 pv f5f8 d6d5 e1e5
info score cp -435 depth 12 nodes 106448053 time 41083 pv f5f8 e7f8
bestmove f5f8 ponder e7f8
```

It's noteworthy that on depth `10`, the score is accurate from the transposition table search.

**Edit**: This position was analysed after the game. During the game, the engine did not have enough time to complete the search to a higher depth, resulting in it playing `e1d1`, which is ridiculous.

Why would this even happen? The engine finds a better move since depth 1, but a different move was found from the transposition table. I also wonder why there is no PV line in the transposition table search.

***My best guess*** would be the search instability quote from Bruce Morland's site here: The Zobrist key does not take into account the path taken to get to a node.  Not every path is the same.  It is possible that the score in a hash element might be based upon a path that would contain a repetition if encountered at some other point in the tree.  A repetition might result in a draw score, or at least a different score.

**Edit**: I tried disabling storing to the table when there is no TFEXACT value. That is, I stopped storing and retrieving TFALPHA/TFBETA values and it works beautifully. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your problem with a deterministic sequence of moves?

Comment: You will need to debug your code. Figure out exactly which code paths are being taken that results in a bad move being played due to the transpositional table check. Add functions to dump the table. Add unit tests for just the table. Print something when you do seem to determine that a transposition has occurred.

Comment: @grek40 Added an example that just took place.

Comment: My best guess is that your hashing is broken. Either it produces collisions way too often, or you don't include some important information (e.g. side to move) in the hash. Try to add code that stores full board position along the hash and check for collisions (i.e. the same hash for different positions) this way.

Comment: @doublep Hashes tested with 'Kiwipete' to depth 7 and initial position to depth 11. Threefold repetition detection works fine. Hash collisions should be very rare, but index collisions are mitigated by storing the hash in. But yeah, this is a possible explanation. I do include side to move/en passant square/castling permissions in the hash. The hashes are generated using mersenne twister too.

Comment: If you use null-move pruning heuristics, do you include number of times it was applied in the hash?

Comment: @doublep I do not... How would that make a difference though? I have a function named `make_null_move()` and `undo_null_move()` that correctly makes a null move (hashes out EP sqaure and swaps the side to play). Shouldn't that take care of it?

Comment: Frankly, my board game skills are somewhat rusty, but as I remember, null moves need to be included in hash in some form. Try enabling transposition table, but disabling null move and see if that helps.

Comment: @doublep Tried null-move pruning disabled, and it still gave away a queen, then moved its King one random square instead of protecting its rook.

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas then. Surely you include the number of moves left (especially important with iterative deepening) in the hash, right?

Comment: @doublep What do you mean by 'number of moves left'?

Comment: @doublep By the way, the entire code is here: https://github.com/servertech/cortex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97561/discussion-between-doublep-and-shreyas-vinod).

Comment: @doublep Take a look at the edit at the end of the post!

Comment: Answered in the chat.

Comment: So did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Fernando I have the same problem, my engine is playing weak after I added TT, looking for the solution

Comment: You can look at my github for my TT code: https://github.com/fernandotenorio/Tunguska

Comment: @Fernando Thank you for the git. I'll look into it :) I ever got around to fixing the issue two years ago.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm also writing an engine with the help of VICE and modifications of its code, and I'm having the exact same problem. Storing only exact scores in the hash table fixes it. Otherwise my engine gives away material and sometimes gets mate scores wrong, but only a little wrong. It's definitely something to do with how alpha and beta bounds are handled, but I can't find or figure out a solution.

Comment: @svadhisthana I didn't, unfortunately. If I do ever get back to it, I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

I do notice that you are *setting* your (pass-by-reference) `pv_move` *before* checking whether your depth criterion is met. Which means that `probe_table` could be changing `pv_move` and still returning `0` (no hit) (and *not* setting `score`). That looks like badness?

Comment: If the hash table entry exists, it is a PV line, and its first element is the PV move, regardless of the depth. The PV move is scored higher as a move and searched first by Alpha-Beta. If the move is found to be bad, it just moves on normally. But, if the entry exists and the depth criterion is met, the relevant score is set using the flag and then probe_table() returns. Alpha-Beta then sees that the depth criterion was met and returns the score for the position without searching. TL;DR It's by design.

Comment: OK, thanks. And thanks for including the Morland link and your code. Comparing your code to the site code, it also looks like Morland never records a TFALPHA hash *inside* the move loop, only after, with thus max alpha. You seem to be storing whenever `alpha==oldalpha`, *inside*. Don't know if that could also make a difference...

Comment: TFALPHA isn't being recorded inside the move loop. TFBETA is inside the move loop whenever a beta cutoff occurs. I'm planning on trying to remove the Alpha/Beta cutoff entries and try with just TFEXACT entries and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Although, you may be right. I'll try using the exact code from Morland.

Comment: Actually, nevermind, it doesn't matter. If `score >= beta` then it returns beta right there after hashing with TFBETA.

Comment: I see, yes. My last question, I promise :-): Morland is counting depth downward to zero. Can't tell for certain from your code, but you're not counting depth upward to a target are you? That would affect the probe depth condition of course if so...

Comment: Just one more comment; not a question so not breaking promise :-): your code assumes a<b and Morland's doesn't. If it's ever the case that a==b, you could be missing some b-cutoffs (and stores). (Some references on a-b pruning I've seen mention possibility a==b.)

Comment: `if(depth == 0) return quiescence(alpha, beta, board, search_info);`. Unlike Morland, I'm not hashing this value in, and I don't know why. I should. Thanks for pointing this out. And you're right, I might be missing some, I'll fix that. But it doesn't explain why this would cause the engine to lose :( (or does it?)